# Parsing a dynamic JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, parsing

I am working on parsing a JSON and searching for specific key in that JSON object. The problem is that the structure of JSON keeps changing and i cannot hard code the path, is there any better ways to parse?

or

can i get this to convert in to regular JSON key value pairs as below

```
{
"resourceName": "Bundle",
"id": "6d6e-81d5-5a1e2b452563",
"lastUpdated": "2069-06-21",
"url": "http://abcd.com",
.
.
.
... so on 
}
```

I have tried using hard coded methods but that doesnt seem to work always

Here is snipped of JSON

```
{
    "resourceName": "Bundle",
    "id": "6d6e-81d5-5a1e2b452563",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2069-06-21"
    },
    "data1": [{
        "url": "http://abcd.com",
        "value": {
            "url": "http://abcd.com",
            "value": [{
                "url": "Severity",
                "value": "info"
            }, {
                "url": "dfew",
                "value": "fefdd"
            }, {
                "url": "fwef",
                "value": "This is data blah blah"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to walk the whole structure and extract *only* the key-value pairs where the value is a string. What about the multiple `url` and `value`, keys?

Comment: If it's constantly changing, but you know the potential options, you might look at implementing [optional chaining](https://medium.com/@danwild.io/optional-chaining-for-javascript-with-babel-7-and-webpack-4-2de8fd9dbdd5)

Comment: @p.s.w.g When there are multiple, I need to take the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search the object recursively:

```
function get_lastUpdated(obj)
{
  for ( var key in obj )
  {
    if ( key == "lastUpdated" ) return obj[key];
    if ( typeof obj[key] == "object" )
    {
      var res = get_lastUpdated(obj[key]);
      if ( res ) return res;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

For a simple case, something like above could work.

Answer (score 0):

When you call [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), you can pass in a callback function, called a `reviver`, which will be recursively applied to all key-value pairs. For example:

```js
var jsonString = `{
    "resourceName": "Bundle",
    "id": "6d6e-81d5-5a1e2b452563",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2069-06-21"
    },
    "data1": [{
        "url": "http://abcd.com",
        "value": {
            "url": "http://abcd.com",
            "value": [{
                "url": "Severity",
                "value": "info"
            }, {
                "url": "dfew",
                "value": "fefdd"
            }, {
                "url": "fwef",
                "value": "This is data blah blah"
            }]
        }
    }]
}`;

var obj = {};
JSON.parse(jsonString, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === "string" && !(key in obj)) {
    obj[key] = value;
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

If have already parsed the object, you can use a similar strategy with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and the `replacer` callback:

```js
var data = {
    "resourceName": "Bundle",
    "id": "6d6e-81d5-5a1e2b452563",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2069-06-21"
    },
    "data1": [{
        "url": "http://abcd.com",
        "value": {
            "url": "http://abcd.com",
            "value": [{
                "url": "Severity",
                "value": "info"
            }, {
                "url": "dfew",
                "value": "fefdd"
            }, {
                "url": "fwef",
                "value": "This is data blah blah"
            }]
        }
    }]
};

var obj = {};
JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === "string" && !(key in obj)) {
    obj[key] = value;
  }
  return value;
});

console.log(obj);
```